# What are the risks of copying MDF/LDF files without detaching the DB first?

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

Our support team have been trained to restore databases by stopping the instance service and then copying a backup of the LDF and MDF files into the folder. All without detaching or attaching the DB from the instance first.

I'm currently trying to write a document describing the appropriate use of detach/attach in this scenario. While I know this is the correct approach, I can't find any resources which describe the risks of the other approach.

Can anyone provide any advice?

Answer (score 2):

No risks, you cannot do that.

There will be no error message when you select the files and press Copy (or Ctrl+C), but when you try to paste them, you'll get the 'File is open in SQl Server' error message.

[image]

You can:

1. Take the database offline and copy the files
2. Stop the SQL Server and copy the files
3. If you need only the database state, create a full database backup
4. If you need the database state and all its transactions, create the full database backup and the transaction log backup

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably can't copy the files without detaching the database first as the files will be in use.
2. Why would you not just use the backup/restore method?